# Is meta the place to ask about bugs?

Tags: support, reputation

For example, [I have 46 upvotes (no down), but only 101 reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/108/tony-meyer) (which is all from association from other sites).  My profile page also says 5 days (2 consecutive) for visits when that should be 7 consecutive days (although that might be a timezone quirk, since IIRC it's US days that matter).

If this isn't the right place to ask, where is?  (And if it is, then I can just edit the title to be the above question).

Comment: FIY, it's UTC days that matter.

Comment: @martinho thanks!

Comment: @Dori thanks - unfortunately, when I asked this, I was at 101 rep, so the graph was completely blank.  I saw upvotes (both my count which I misread as votes for my stuff, and for my answers individually), but didn't remember about CW, so didn't understand why the total (and the graph) didn't include them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those 46 upvotes are votes *that you've cast*, not received.

Your answers have recieved a total of 8 upvotes, but 7 of those are on answers flagged as Community Wiki, and thus award no reputation. Thus, you have 1 upvote, and the appropriate 10 rep.

That said, in answer to your initial question: Yes. Meta is the place to ask about bugs. For bugs that you suspect to be specific to SciFi.SE (i.e. CSS or layout bugs, or rep oddities unique to this site), meta.scifi is the place. For bugs that affect the entire network or stackexchange engine, [Meta.StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) is the place to go.

Comment: Incidentally, this raises an important point about the fact that the *vast majority* of the site is currently getting flagged as Community Wiki, which, to say the least, does very bad things to any hope of a stable reputation economy emerging.

Comment: @dori I'd hope so. This is my first time back in a week after seeing what a wreck the site was on day one, and the general enthusiasm on meta for encouraging this sort of nonsense. I am... not encouraged by what I see coming back. :/

Comment: @dori - Every last one of them.

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten about CW. Thanks x2!